# How can I install Ubuntu on a MacBook Air?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, macbook-air

How can I install Ubuntu on a MacBook Air? I want it to dual boot, is it possible?

Do I get any benefits by installing Ubuntu or Linux?  Because OS X has Unix tools like `bash`, isn't is the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can install Ubuntu on a Mac Air, you can also dual boot. There's a lot of information out there, but some good Ubuntu sites already cover what you want:

I recomend reading this two:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20Air%20using%20live%20CD

Answer (score 1):

Good new is , Yes it is possible.
the benefits I guess are distribution specific and will probably come down to which you like more. Yes they both use bash although functionally i think their a little different, or maybe its just a little more useful on linux.

As for the actual process i found a guide [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-macbook-air-3-1-via-usb-flash-drive)

I think that unless your sure this is a procedure you are in need of , a better solution would be to try ubuntu (or another distribution) as a live CD or inside you mac using [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org) or another virtualization software

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the recommended approach to installing Ubuntu on a MacBook Air depends on your hardware version. I believe it is best to start with this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir

It will show you how to discover your Air's version and provide you with links to proper installation instructions.